# Storing and retrieving rows from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following code:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
$questions = array();
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['vastamine'])) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
        }


    $_SESSION['vastamine']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['vastamine']['index'] = 0;
    $count = count($questions);
    $_SESSION['vastamine']['count'] = $count;
}
$x = $_SESSION['vastamine']['index'];
    echo $_SESSION['vastamine']['questions'][$x];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['vastamine']['index']++;
    $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['vastamine']['questions'][$x] . '"');
    $q_id = mysql_result($result2, 0);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO vastused (vastus_id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
    }

?>
<br>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" style="width:300px; height:150px;"><br>
<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Vasta">
</form>
```

It is meant for taking questions from database. It takes only question which have kysimustik_id=pollid. After that it displays all the questions one by one and when the submit button is clicked, it stores every answer into database one by one. Everything works just fine, but I have one problem. I have two questions in database, but when I run this code in my browser it displays first question, then I answer and click submit and after that it displays first queston again. then I answer it again. After that it shows second question too, but when I answer that, the answer wont be stored into database. It only stores two first answers into database and shows it like the second answer I gave to first question is answer to second question.

I tried to change

```
$_SESSION['vastamine']['index'] = 0;
```

And gave it a value:

```
$_SESSION['vastamine']['index'] = 1;
```

It didn't help. After that it shows second question two times.
What should I change in my code so browser would display every question one time and stores answers right way?

Comment: You're using `POST` for your form but you call the `pollid` from `GET`. Where does is come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some sort, I don't know your architecture, but I think you can try this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '" ORDER BY `kysimus_id` ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this flow is not so good to use, it looks a bad one,

You just need to upgrade your code by the proper way.
Your first query is good, it will return the records from the 'kysimused' based on pollid condition, now for the second step try to use loop condition or create one on records which are fetch from the database, and do your process on that id's

Here you are doing just for the single record, you are creating a single records array and process on it,